# How to trigger the auto-hide icon in c#?

Tags: c#, show-hide, notifyicon

I have an application. If the application is not being used for a certain amount if time, it should hide. When application is hidden and we mouse-over the icon, it should be restored.

How can I do this? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like JesseJames said, use a timer to measure the inactive time of the application and hide it after an amount of time. Re-activate it when the mouse is hovered over the NotifyIcon. Here's a sample ***WindowsForms*** solution that does the job:

```
private Timer _timer;
private int _ticks;

public Form1()
{
    _timer = new Timer { Interval = 1000, Enabled = true };
    _timer.Tick += TimerTick;

    Activated += Form1_Activated;
    MouseMove += Form1_MouseMove;
    //notifyIcon1 is an icon set through the designer
    notifyIcon1.MouseMove += NotifyIcon1MouseMove;
}

protected void TimerTick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //After 5 seconds the app will be hidden
    if (_ticks++ == 5)
    {
        WindowState = FormWindowState.Minimized;
        Hide();
        _timer.Stop();
        _ticks = 0;
    }
}

protected void NotifyIcon1MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    WindowState = FormWindowState.Normal;
    Show();
    _ticks = 0;
    _timer.Start();
}

protected void Form1_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    _ticks = 0;
}
```

Perhaps there might exist a cleaner solution, I don't know, but it gets you on the way. Same principle will go for WPF, only the code will be slightly different. Hope this helps!

Answer (score 2):

You have to define a timer in your application that will count the time when mouse is not over the form/window. Then just hide your application.

Download [WPF NotifyIcon](http://www.hardcodet.net/projects/wpf-notifyicon) 
And handle MouseOver event, that will show Form/Window

**EDIT:**

If you do not need to minimize application to tray and hide window keeping it on desktop -> use the same algorithm, but do not hide the window, just set transparency to 0% or 10%. When mouse is over - set transparency to 100%.

Comment: I'd prefer your first method. If the app is transparent, you can still interact with it right? Therefore I thinks it's "safer" to hide/minimize the app...

Answer (score 0):

To see if the user has made any input you can use a similar approach like [this](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/13384/Getting-the-user-idle-time-with-C) one. To get your application visible again you need a way to get the global mouse and maybe keyboard input, to do this you can use hooks, you can find one solution for that [here](http://support.microsoft.com/default.aspx?scid=kb;en-us;318804). And if the hook is triggered it really just depends on what kind of UI you are using, but calling specific `hide` or `show` methods should be suffice.